# garbage collection - does mark+sweep have to be monolithic/atomic

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, micropython

*This discussion will use the micropython code but since it's so simple, I hope it will be useful to the general discussion of mark+sweep*

[Micropython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython) uses garbage collection, specifically mark-and-sweep; let's define that.

[image: garbage collection]

**Mark**
During the **mark** phase, the `gc` follows memory references and literally **marks** the used memory blocks to indicate they are reachable from the set of root blocks.

**Sweep**
After the mark phase is complete, the sweeper loops over the entire heap and if a memory block is used but not **marked** it means it is unreachable by the code so it is "freed" i.e. tagged as **free**. The memory blocks which were marked during the **mark** phase have that mark removed.

The current implementation requires an atomic call to perform garbage collection aka `gc` but I've been wondering if it's possible to split it up into multiple calls as opposed to a monolithic/atomic call.

This would help reduce jitter: instead of one big timing hit, you'd have a bunch of smaller calls spread out. (The implementation details of how you'd "spread out" the `gc` calls are not discussed here . . . unless someone thinks it would add to the discussion.)

If `gc` is running "in the background" - in-between bytecodes or [after pre-defined bytecodes](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/3ea0862a6e3c97f6224548c41a225f270df4d205/py/vm.c#L1295) - then an allocation (or deallocation) at the wrong point could result in a race-condition and heap corruption. Before we can split up `gc` execution, we have to determine the possible race conditions.

The two operations that can be performed are: allocation and deallocation.

### Allocation

What could happen if the user performs an allocation in the middle of either the mark or sweep phase?

Let's look at a concrete code example

```
>> var1 = SomeAllocation()
```

**Allocation during mark**
In the above example, a statement is executed in the REPL so any additions to the dictionary would be to the global dictionary which is an entry in the `GC Roots`. If an entry is added to globals before it is scanned, nothing "bad" happens: the new memory block will be **marked** as it should be.

The problem is if globals is modified *after* it has been scanned. In that case, the memory block wouldn't be **marked** so during the sweep phase, it would be considered "unreachable" and freed . . . even though it shouldn't be.

**Allocation during sweep**
If a block is allocated before the sweeper has traversed that point in memory, it will free it because it doesn't have the special **mark** from the **mark** phase. If a block is allocated after the sweeper has traversed said block, nothing bad happens.

**Solution**

If `gc` is in the middle of executing, tag the allocated block as **marked**. The only downside is that if you allocate in phase sweep and after sweeper has checked the newly-allocated block, you'll finish up `gc` with a block tagged with **mark**. Unless user explicitly frees it, you'll need to go through an extra `gc` cycle to free it if it becomes unreachable.

But there's a simple solution to that: if you allocate during phase sweep, you check the position of the sweeper: if new-block-to-be-allocated is behind it, do not tag it with a **mark** and otherwise, do tag it with a **mark** because the sweeper would've removed a **mark**. This way you will not exit `gc` with blocks tagged with **mark**.

### Deallocation

What could happen if the user performs an allocation in the middle of either the mark or sweep phase?

**Deallocation during mark**

If a block is **freed** before a referencing (parent) block is scanned, nothing happens.

If a block is **freed** and it has children that have already been **marked**, we have an inconsistency because blocks should only be **marked** if they have a parent that is also **marked** (or parent is a `GC root`). The result is that these unreachable but marked blocks will not get freed until an additional `gc` cycle because having been **marked**, these parent-less but **marked** blocks will not be freed by phase sweep.

However, I do not think this is a problem because this wouldn't be any different from the case of a monolithic `gc`. In a monolithic `gc`, you'd have to finish the current `gc` cycle, then user would call `free(ptr)` and then that block's children would be freed during next `gc`. The amount of time until the heap is in the "correct" state would not change.

**Deallocation during sweep**

If a block is **freed** before sweeper checks it, nothing special happens. The **free** operation changes the target block's status from **marked** to **free** and then when the sweeper reaches it . . . nothing to see here just a free block.

If a block is **freed** after sweeper checks it, the **free** operation changes the target block's status from **used** to **free**.

**QUESTION**

Is my analysis correct: is it possible to split up mark+sweep garbage collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Java has had a [Concurrent Mark-Sweep (CMS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/concurrent-mark-sweep-cms-collector.htm) collector since version 1.4 (2002). It works similarly to how you describe.

If you run [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), I imagine you could take advantage of it natively today.

Comment: Unfortunately it'll have to be ported/implemented in micropython. But thank you for confirming this idea has merit.

Comment: Note that in the Java world CMS is usually used alongside a different collector strategy for the young generation. That allows more efficient allocation (using a modified twospace allocator, which is roughly as fast as stack allocation), with objects only needing to be handled by the mark-sweep process once they become "tenured".