# How CPython knows which objects are unmarked after performing mark-sweep algorithm?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cpython

I understand how CPython performs reference counting. The following C-structure shows that `ob_refcnt` stores the number of references to an object.

```
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

But I don't understand how CPython figures out which objects are **unmarked** after performing mark-sweep algorithm? Looks like it has some global list of all objects?

Comment: It doesn't sweep objects, it sweeps memory blocks. The garbage collector follows the linked list starting from the GC roots and marks all memory locations that are in use. Then it assumes that anything that has not been marked in the previous step is garbage, hence the "collect" step.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439859/garbage-collection-does-marksweep-have-to-be-monolithic-atomic) for a similar discussion.